# Why does aggregate GROUPBY() COUNT(*) of 0's not show up in the query?

Tags: sql-server, date, group-by, count, recursive-query

This is a problem I'm not sure I've run into before (and frankly didn't know it existed). I am grouping by YEAR and MONTH for monthly time-series analysis but COUNTs of 0's are not showing up in the output. Here is the query:

```
SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
        ORDER BY YEAR(order_date), MONTH(order_date)) AS 'Index',
    YEAR(order_date) AS 'Year',
    MONTH(order_date) AS 'Month',
    CONCAT(CASE
                WHEN MONTH(order_date) = 1 THEN 'Jan'
                WHEN MONTH(order_date) = 2 THEN 'Feb'
                WHEN MONTH(order_date) = 3 THEN 'Mar'
                WHEN MONTH(order_date) = 4 THEN 'Apr'
                WHEN MONTH(order_date) = 5 THEN 'May'
                WHEN MONTH(order_date) = 6 THEN 'Jun'
                WHEN MONTH(order_date) = 7 THEN 'Jul'
                WHEN MONTH(order_date) = 8 THEN 'Aug'
                WHEN MONTH(order_date) = 9 THEN 'Sep'
                WHEN MONTH(order_date) = 10 THEN 'Oct'
                WHEN MONTH(order_date) = 11 THEN 'Nov'
                WHEN MONTH(order_date) = 12 THEN 'Dec'
            END,
            ' ',
            YEAR(order_date)) AS 'Timeline',
    COUNT(*) AS 'Pending Cases'
FROM dbo.result_management_report
WHERE final_reported_date IS NULL
AND order_type = 'Commercial'
AND test_name = 'CTC-FISH'
GROUP BY YEAR(order_date), MONTH(order_date)
ORDER BY YEAR(order_date), MONTH(order_date)
```

Here is the output. You can see that where Jan 2020, it is missing instead of the Pending Cases being "0"

[image: sqloutput]

I've tried IIF and NULLIF and ISNULL but to no avail. If someone knows a trick to help me here it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Bear in mind that every row shown in your result is there because *at least one row with those values* (for `GROUP BY`) existed in the input.

Comment: Hi Damien, yup that's what I'm asking. Is there anyway to display "0" for those rows that do not have any entries?

Answer (score 0):

They are not showing because they are not available in your souce table.

One option to work around this is to `left join` a list of fixed dates, that you can generate with a recursive cte:

```
with all_dates as (
    select 
        datefromparts(year(min(orderdate)), month(min(orderdate)), 1) dt
        datefromparts(year(max(orderdate)), max(min(orderdate)), 1) maxdt
    from dbo.result_management_report
    union all
    select dateadd(month, 1, dt), maxdt 
    from all_dates
    where dt < maxdt
)
select  
    row_number() over(order by d.dt) as idx,
    d.dt start_of_month,
    count(r.orderdate) pending_cases
from all_dates d
left join bo.result_management_report r 
    on  r.orderdate >= d.dt 
    and r.orderdate <  dateadd(month, 1, d.dt)
    and r.final_reported_date is null
    and r.order_type = 'commercial'
    and r.test_name = 'ctc-fish'
group by d.dt
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use in `where final_reported_date IS NULL` it will get all the data

Comment: That condition is something that needs to be there. And I don't think this really answers the question. Let's say even if I didn't include that clause, if the total number of cases is still zero in that particular month, it still won't show up.